# How to trigger two or three clicks in a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to click a button or li on document ready, in this case twice or more, depending on the JavaScript loop.

The below code will alert from 1 to 2 but will only trigger once, any idea's how to trigger based on the loop  i++

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; ){
        $("#inc"+this_item.food_menu_id+"").trigger("click");
        i++;
    }
});
```

The trigger will only execute the once.

I need to execute as per the number of i result. i.e 2 triggers not one.

Comment: *"will only trigger once"* - [says who](https://jsfiddle.net/6ovm7c3w/)?

Comment: my guess is the click code limits it and has nothing to do with the code above

Answer (score 1):

1. You need is to store the element in variable to make the loop executed normally
2. Your loop isn't on the right way you should done it like that

> HTML

```
<div id="elem">click</div>
```

> Vanillajs

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elem"), n = 0;
elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
   n++;
   alert("trigger ("+n+")\n");
});
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  elem.click();
}
```

> jQuery

```
var n = 0, e = $("#elem");
e.click(function () {
    n++;
    alert("trigger ("+n+")\n");
});
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  e.trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: each code loops 1-4  I can see it in the console.log but its only trigger the click once and not 5 times as per the loop.

Comment: You need to store the element in variable i edited the answer and added full html & js